# Has anyone used the DataGridView-Filter-Popup-Extensions from Vincenzo Rossi?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have managed to successfully implement and use the DataGridView-Filter-Popup-Extensions of Vincenzo Rossi. But I am having an issue with the DgvMultiCheckBoxColumnFilter on my DataGridView Columns.

The Filter is there and I can select multiple items but the Filter does not take effect at all whether it is a single selection or multiple selection.

Any assistance or information on this would be appreciated .

EDIT - HERE IS THE CODE

```
Dim strSQL2 As String = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(OrderID AS INT) AS OrderID FROM taSalesData"

Dim dt2 As New DataTable
Dim clssqldata As New clsSqlData

dt2 = clssqldata.sqlFillDataTable(strSQL2, 1)

   
Dim filterManager2 As New DgvFilterManager()

AddHandler filterManager2.ColumnFilterAdding, AddressOf fm_ColumnFilterAdding2

   
DataGridView2.DataSource = dt2

filterManager2.DataGridView = DataGridView2
  
filterManager2("OrderID") = New DgvMultiCheckBoxColumnFilter

Private Sub fm_ColumnFilterAdding2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ColumnFilterEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Column.Name

            Case "OrderID"
                e.ColumnFilter = New DgvMultiCheckBoxColumnFilter()



        End Select
    End Sub
```

Kind Regards

Comment: You will need to provide the code where the problem occurs.

Comment: Hi @Mary, Thanks for the response, I have now included the code in my post as requested: